# task-launcher-cloudfoundry Application is getting into disk out of memory after several times launching of task

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I launched a task using trigger task for every 20 min | task-launcher-cloudfoundry in PCF.
task-launcher-cloudfoundry generally downloads the task jar supplied by trigger task and keep inside temp folder like

```
Downloading [https://appregister-acp.pre.ptlapps.com/UTVINSummary_Task-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar] to /home/vcap/tmp/spring-cloud-deployer4679647774227645681/b955e68a620b6feba7e9ebf6970788b16c6fbec0

`So every time triggertask send task information based on it interval setting to task-launcher-cloudfoundry then task jar get downloaded to temp location of this app which leads to using up of allocated disk memory completely and leads to errors like`

2018-12-20T18:00:16.867-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /home/vcap/tmp/spring-cloud-deployer7629046795282951794: Disk quota exceeded
```
and finally task doesn't get launched after few triggers [ as per schedule on triggertask ]

Stream Definition:

`stream create  testTrigger10 --definition "triggertask  --uri=https://app123s.com/abc.jar  --triggertask.application-name='kk_test_518PM'    --trigger.fixed-delay=1500  --triggertask.environment-properties='spring.cloud.task.name=Task_temp' | task-launcher-cloudfoundry  --maven.remote-repositories.repo1.url=https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot   --spring.cloud.deployer.cloudfoundry.url=ABC.com   --spring.cloud.deployer.cloudfoundry.org=SCDF-acceptance  --spring.cloud.deployer.cloudfoundry.space=scdf-acp-space     --spring.cloud.deployer.cloudfoundry.taskTimeout=1000" --deploy`

task-launcher-cloudfoundry Application specifications : 1GB disk space , 1 GB memory

So app is reaching 1GB disk space after 7 iterations.So even if i increase disk space to 2GB also at one point I may face this issue again after some trigger calls from tasktrigger.

How to cleanup downloaded task jar after launching the task ? Is there any parameter available to clean up disk space ?

Note: task-launcher-cloudfoundry App is not in crashed state. It will be running state with throwing exceptions.

Full Stack Error :

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/2713

Answer (score 0):

The same question was posted here and also as a GitHub issue.

Four different options were described in the GitHub issue. For more details, see [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/2713#issuecomment-449986585](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/2713#issuecomment-449986585).